# Optimise the condition if else xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, optimization, xamarin

How to optimise if else condition for tableview cell color

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath){

    var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (TableCell.Key) as TableCell;
    if (cell == null)
        cell = new TableCell ();
        cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;

    if (indexPath.Row % 2 == 0) {
            cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        }   else {
            cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.LightGray;
    }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is little here left to be optimized. The only thing I'd change is the last `if` - I'd replace it with a conditional expression:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath){
    var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (TableCell.Key) as TableCell;
    if (cell == null) {
        cell = new TableCell ();
    }
    cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
    cell.BackgroundColor = (indexPath.Row % 2 == 0) ? UIColor.White : UIColor.LightGray;
}
```

This is a matter of personal preference, though: your `if` statement with two assignments was perfectly readable too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use ?? for the cell creation:

```
var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (TableCell.Key) as TableCell ?? new TableCell();
```

From the looks of it this might also be a slight improvement as the Accessory seems to be a static type and doesn't need to be assigned every single time:

```
var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (TableCell.Key) as TableCell 
    ?? new TableCell() { Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator };
```